# Is there a hash of a class instance in Python?

Tags: python

Let's suppose I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a
```

And I construct such instances:

```
obj1 = MyClass(5)
obj2 = MyClass(12)
obj3 = MyClass(5)
```

Is there a **general** way to hash my objects such that objects constructed with same values have equal hashes? In this case:

```
myhash(obj1) != myhash(obj2)
myhash(obj1) == myhash(obj3)
```

By **general** I mean a Python function that can work with objects created by any class I can define. For different classes and same values the hash function must return different results, of course; otherwise this question would be about hashing of several arguments instead.

Comment: What if the first class is a subclass of the second and the values are the same?

Comment: These are different classes so the hashes must be different.

Comment: Are you sure? That breaks the Liskov substitution principle and may lead to confusing errors. People generally expect subclasses to behave similarly. Of course it might still be what you want, just consider it carefully.

Comment: There is no way to achieve the inequality guarantee you've asked for.

Comment: @AlexHall Even if you can provide a solution that keeps the Liskov substitution principle, I can modify it by adding __class__.__name__ and get exactly what I want. So your question actually does not matter in my case.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: Class `__name__`s are far from distinct, and that still wouldn't solve the problem of hash collision, or dealing with unhashable types, or the many other problems this quest runs into.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thank you, it is a good notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def myhash(obj):
    items = sorted(obj.__dict__.items(), key=lambda it: it[0])
    return hash((type(obj),) + tuple(items))
```

This solution obviously has limitations:

- It assumes that all fields in `__dict__` are important.
- It assumes that `__dict__` is present, e.g. this won't work with `__slots__`.
- It assumes that all values are hashable
- It breaks the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: Not a good solution, because I can have two different classes with the same name and, secondly, the arguments passed to `__init__` won't go to `__dict__` always.

Comment: @Fomalhaut this looks at the class, not the class name. And how can you expect any function to detect any kind of difference between objects if the dicts are the same?

Comment: Yes, I see, my comment about class name is wrong, than you. As for the same dicts, different initial arguments may act differently somewhere else and save the same dicts in the end.

Comment: @Fomalhaut if two objects have the same dicts then they have the same values. It doesn't matter if they had different initial arguments, those aren't stored anywhere and will not affect behaviour after `__init__` completes if the dicts are the same.

Comment: You are right, you convinced me. Your solution works fine in my particular task.

Answer (score 0):

The question is badly formed for a couple reasons:

- Hashes don't test eqaulity, just inequality.  That is, they guarantee that `hash(a) != hash(b)` implies `a != b`, but the reverse does not hold true.   For example, checking `"aKey" in myDict` will do a linear search through all keys in `myDict` that have the same hash as `"aKey"`.
- You seem to wanting to do something with storage.  Note that the hash of `"aKey"` will change between runs, so don't write it to a file.   See the bottom of [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) for more information.
- In general, you need to think carefully about subclasses, hashes, and equality.  There is a pit here, so even the official documentation quietly sidesteps what the hash of instance means.  Do note that each instance has a `__dict__` for local variables and the `__class__` with more information.

Hope this helps those who come after you.